# Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'setSize' of undefined in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When I start CKEditor in Chrome, I get next error:

```
Uncaught Type Error cannot read property 'setSize'  of undefined ckeditor.js:323
```

This is line from script:

```
 f.setSize("width",a,true);g&&(g.style.width="1%");j.setStyle("height",Math.max(b-(d?0:(f.$.offsetHeight||0)-(j.$.clientHeight||0)),0)+"px");g&&(g.style.width=
    "100%");this.fire("resize")};CKEDITOR.editor.prototype.getResizable=function(a){return a?this.ui.space("contents"):this.container};CKEDITOR.domReady(function(){CKEDITOR.replaceClass&&CKEDITOR.replaceAll(CKEDITOR.replaceClass)})})();CKEDITOR.config.startupMode="wysiwyg";
```

Can anybody help me with this error? Thanks

Comment: Can you try replacing this line `CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) { ev.editor.fire('contentDom'); });` in your `config.js` with `startupFocus : true` and then clear your browser cache and try again?

Comment: But I don't have this line in my config.js

Comment: Can you please post the content of your `config.js` file here?

Comment: /**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2015, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
 // config.language = 'fr';
 // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
};

Comment: Okay. Can you try adding, `CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) { ev.editor.fire('contentDom'); });` as a last line in your `config.js`